# Convergence in probability of the sum of scheme of series

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables

Could you please help with this one. It looks like smth simple but I can't figure it out.

Let $\{x_{in}\}, \ i=1,\dots, n, \ n=1,\dots,\infty$ be the scheme of series of random variables. For each $n$ random variables $\{x_{in}\}, \ i=1,\dots,n,$ are i.i.d. Moreover for each $i$ we have $x_{in}\stackrel{P} \rightarrow 0, \ n\to \infty.$

Is it true that
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{in}\stackrel{P}\rightarrow 0, \quad n\to\infty \ ?
$$

Notice that $x_{in}$ may be random variables that don't have expactations and variances.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $x_{i,n}$ such that for each $n$, $\mathbb P\{x_{i,n}=n\}=c_n$ and $\mathbb P\{x_{i,n}=0\}=1-c_n$. Then pick the sequence $(c_n,n\geqslant 1)\subset [0,1]$ such that:

1. $\lim_{n\to\infty}c_n=0$, and
2. $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1-c_n)^n\neq 1$.